# In tomcat deploy mulitple apps with some context but make them think as they are root app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, iis, glassfish

I am not sure what I am asking is correct approach or not. So, let me first clarify my requirement.

Till date I was using each app as a root app and was deploying them in separate tomcat instance, but my app number are now growing and I can not keep on deploying a separate instance of tomcat for each app.

There are two things which make me deploy every app as root:

1. For updating an app you have to shutdown tomcat instance which will also stops other app running in same instance. And I do not want this to happen (as some users are live on one web app or some job is running on some app, so I can not stop all apps at any given time).
2. For writing urls, if I deploy a web app as root, then in web-app I can simply write "/students/list" , but if I deploy them in same instance with some different context name, then I have to write context name before the urls, like "ctxt1/students/list"

And for developers sake I don't want them to write context name before every url in web-app and also I don't want context names to appear to a user.

Is there any approach with which I can solve these 2 problems. I am thinking of migrating to Glassfish for some apps. If glassfish offer solution to these problems then I can migrate all apps to glassfish as well

Secondly I am running tomcat behind IIS, using ISAPI. If IIS can be of any help here?

Comment: So you want to deploy all the apps into root context? What if two of them would listen to the same URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use one tomcat per App. The amount of tomcats should increase only when needed (really needed).

It is not true that you have to kill the whole tomcat, for one App update, you should only restart the specific context (going to http://your.tomcat:8080/manager/html).

About the URLs you can use an apache in front with mod_proxy_ajp configured to talk with tomcat (see this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html)

Comment: Oh yes, I got my answer for my 1st question.
But your second answer will address user's request. But I am also concerned about developers who are working directly with tomcat. E.g, For root, I can write `response.sendRedirect("/students/list");` . Having a context (ctxt) in place, I have to write `response.sendRedirect("ctxt/students/list");`
But `ctxt` can change someday, or it also just cluttering the url, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html#context.xml_-_approach__1. Maybe the approach #2 is your solution.

Comment: Ahhh and remember if my answer was useful to you somehow, pleeease vote me up

Comment: Yes, I always take care of voting up :) . Approach 2nd seems perfect, will try with it. Do you know something similar for glassfish also?

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of glassfish is near zero. Let's say that it is not zero because I know of its existence ;)